# How can I turn an anonymous type into a key value pair object

Tags: c#

I'm trying to figure out a clean way of getting data back from my web service that is key/value pair.

Is there a way to take a query like this:

```
            var q = db.Ratings.Select(x => new
                                     {
                                         x.pro,
                                         x.con,
                                         x.otherThoughts,
                                         x.Item.title,
                                         x.score,
                                         x.subject
                                     });
```

And just return a key value pair where the key would be the columns listed above, with their corresponding value?

Rather than creating a separate class?

```
myDict.Add("pro", q.pro);
myDict.Add("con", q.con);
```

This is not efficient and creating a class like this isn't either, especially if I have dozens of methods:

```
public class Rating
{
  public string pro { get; set; }
  public string con { get; set; }
}
```

All of my searches turn up examples that contain the previous two code samples.

Comment: It should be fairly easy to write a method that reflects over an object and returns the right `Dictionary<string,object>`.

Alternatively you could look into using `dynamic`. However, not that such approaches are flakey in medium-trust envrionments so be careful if you are deploying to a shared-hosted website.

Comment: Why do you think opting for non-descriptive dictionary is a *cleaner* approach than returning a class?

Comment: If I have 30 methods in a web service called Ajax, now I have 30 methods and 30 classes, dumb.

Comment: I would do the 30 lines of typing to get to the example with new class -- or better, automate the task ;-) The first approach loses static typing (which I think is generally bad) unless the keys are well, truly dynamic. If you do use the class then it's just a simple modification of the original query: `new MyType { con = ... }`

Comment: No sympathy here. It's a thought process like that one that has the application I'm presently working on in utter shambles. Intead of strongly-typed objects that fully describe what they encapsulate, I'm stuck on an application that passes DataSets around like candy. No idea what's in them, no idea where they came from, unwinding the mess is nigh impossible. Take the *extra few minutes* to create a class and thank yourself later. If you opt for your approach, I wish you good fortune.

Comment: @Anthony, I agree with you, but in this case I think strongly typed is not needed here, only javascript will be accessing this data. It will not be referenced by server side methods. An Ajax call contains enough information to find the method, once I look the method up I can see exactly what keys is passing, very simple and clean to maintain.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't recommend to use the 'untyped' approach that you are looking at.
I would use typed objects instead, the ones that you don't want to create.

However, here is the answer to your question. You can use DataTable object for what you need. Like this:

```
var items = new[]
{
    new Item { Id = 1, Name = "test1" }, 
    new Item { Id = 2, Name = "test2" }
};

var dataTable = new DataTable();
var propeties = typeof(Item).GetProperties();
Array.ForEach(propeties, arg => dataTable.Columns.Add(arg.Name, arg.PropertyType));
Array.ForEach(items, item => dataTable.Rows.Add(propeties.Select(arg => arg.GetValue(item, null)).ToArray()));
return dataTable;
```